# vscodium: pass arguments for debugging

Tags: debugging, vscodium

I want to debug a command line program that uses arguments. Like "cat <argument>".
How do I set such an argument in my debugger to check if my program is handling this argument in an expected way?

Did not find anything in vs docs.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow :) What Editor/IDE/debugger are you using? VS Code, IntelliJ, Visual Studio or something else? And What language is your program written in? Cheers :)

Comment: Ah, I just read that you are using VS Code. Still, what language is your program written in?

Comment: It's python. But I think it doesn't matter. vscodium is just a UI (nice) for development. I hope there is a general way in vscodium to offer those arguments to the application.